# match with group of stop words and replace with empty space in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I have address column in a table as shown below

```
 >>> spark.sql("select add1 from test").show(10,False)
+---------------------------+
|add1                       |
+---------------------------+
|PO BOX 1111DUBAI  UAE      |
|P.O. BOX 2222DUBAI - U.A.E|
+---------------------------+
```

I have to match with group of words and remove them from the column just for comparing purpose

I was able to replace a single word with empty space like below ('UAE' in this case)

```
spark.sql("select regexp_replace(add1,'UAE','') from test").show(10,False)
+---------------------------+
|regexp_replace(add1, UAE, )|
+---------------------------+
|PO BOX 1111DUBAI           |
|P.O. BOX 2222DUBAI - U.A.E|
+---------------------------+
```

But I would like to remove all special characters and a group of stop words like {'UAE','U.A.E', 'U A E', 'PO', 'P O'}

Desired Output :

```
spark.sql("select regexp_replace(add1,'UAE','') from test").show(10,False)
+---------------------------+
|regexp_replace(add1, UAE, )|
+---------------------------+
|1111DUBAI                  |
|2222DUBAI                  |
+---------------------------+
```

Can someone help me to achieve this pls , Thanks !

Comment: don't you think it would better to "keep" a certain pattern instead of removing everything else ?

Comment: I also agree with @Steven. why don't you try to get the required one by using `regexp_extract`?

Comment: not all addresses have PO box numbers, they have street names and we are fine with them and only those addresses with PO box numbers must be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do it. Hoping it solve all your cases.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

stop_words = {'UAE','U.A.E', 'U A E', 'PO', 'P O', 'BOX'}

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "add1",
    F.regexp_replace(F.col("add1"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "")
)

for stop_word in stop_words: 
    df2 = df2.withColumn(
        "add1",
        F.trim(F.regexp_replace(F.col("add1"), stop_word, ""))
    )

df2.show()

+---------+
|     add1|
+---------+
|1111DUBAI|
|2222DUBAI|
+---------+
```